# What is the correct way to override an interface method to ensure that it can only be used on objects of identical types?

Tags: java, oop, interface, overriding, parameterization

I am creating a `Matrix` class in Java to use in a linear algebra program. Right now it holds doubles, but I want to abstract it.

I've created an interface called `MatrixElement`, which will contain `add`, `multiply`, `divide`, and any other arithmetic methods needed to perform these matrix operations.

Here is a snippet of the `Matrix` class:

```
public class Matrix<T extends MatrixElement> {

    private ArrayList<ArrayList<T>> rows;

    public Matrix(int numRows, int numCols) {

        if (numRows <= 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Matrix must have at least one row.");
        }

        if (numCols <= 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Matrix must have at least one column.");
        }

        this.rows = new ArrayList<ArrayList<T>>();

        for (int r = 0; r < numRows; r++) {
            ArrayList<T> row = new ArrayList<T>();
            for (int c = 0; c < numCols; c++) {
                row.add(new T());
            }
            this.rows.add(row);
        }

    }

     /* lots of methods omitted */

     public static Matrix sum(Matrix a, Matrix b) {

        if (a.numRows() != b.numRows() || a.numCols() != b.numCols()) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Matrices must be the same size.");
        }

        Matrix sum = new Matrix(a.numRows(), b.numCols());

        for (int r = 1; r <= b.numRows(); r++) {
            for (int c = 1; c <= b.numCols(); c++) {
                sum.setEntry(r, c, a.getEntry(r, c).add(b.getEntry(r, c)));
            }
        }

        return sum;

    }

    public Matrix add(Matrix matrix) {
        return Matrix.sum(this, matrix);
    }

}
```

Here is how methods are declared in `MatrixElement`

```
public interface MatrixElement {
    public MatrixElement add(MatrixElement e);
}
```

Finally, here's a sample class I've created that implements this interface:

```
public class Fraction implements MatrixElement {

    private BigInteger numerator;
    private BigInteger denominator;

    public Fraction(int num, int denom) {
        numerator = BigInteger.valueOf(num);
        denominator = BigInteger.valueOf(denom);
    }

    @Override
    public Fraction add(MatrixElement e) {

        Fraction f;

        try {
            f = (Fraction) e;
        } catch (ClassCastException cce) {
            throw new IllegalMatrixOperationException("Cannot add " + this.getClass().toString() + " and " + e.getClass().toString());
        }

        /* addition code omitted */

        return this;

    }
}
```

The main idea here is this:

- `Matrix` objects can hold instances of any one class that implements the interface `MatrixElement`
- `MatrixElement` contains arithmetic methods necessary for matrix manipulation, such as `add`
- The kicker: Classes that implement `MatrixElement` can only use its methods on other instances of the same class. For example, `Fraction` can only be added to other `Fraction` instances. Two classes may implement `MatrixElement`, **but they shouldn't necessarily be able to add to one another.**

I ran this design by another programmer and was told that casting like this is bad practice. If so, what is the correct way to do this? How can I use an interface to 'group' classes that have similar functionality to be used in parameterization, but then restrict which children of said interface can be used in the children's methods?

Comment: `new T()` will not compile

Comment: `public static <T extends MatrixElement> Matrix<T> sum(Matrix<T> a, Matrix<T> b)`

Comment: @Lashane @ElliotFrisch thank you for pointing those out. I haven't written the generic version of `Matrix` yet so I expect some syntax errors. That piece was mainly provided to give context. My question is in the implementation of the `MatrixElement` interface

Comment: it is not about syntax, it is about concept, java cannot compile such code, because generics in java are very different than templates in c++

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two requirements for generics in the post above.

> **Requirement 1**: Elements that can be added to other elements of the same type

You would like to impose a contract on certain data types so that instances of those types can be added to other instances of the same type, and same type only. The intention is to support the following kinds of operations:

```
int + int = int
long + long = long
real fraction + real fraction = real fraction
complex number + complex number = complex number
```

This contract can be expressed as follows:

```
public interface MatrixElement<T> {
  T add(T e);
}
```

In simple language, this contract says that a `MatrixElement` is a type whose instances can be added to other instances of the same type to yield yet another instance of the same type, which is what was required.

> **Requirement 2**: Two-dimensional matrices of elements, all of the same type can be added to other two-dimensional matrices of elements of the same type and same dimensions

This contract can be expressed as:

```
public class Matrix<T extends MatrixElement<T>> {
  public Matrix<T> add (Matrix<T> another) { ... }
}
```

This contract says that a `Matrix` consists of elements of type `MatrixElement`, such that all elements are of the same type. The `Matrix` also allows addition with another `Matrix`, provided both have elements of the same type. The result is returned as a third `Matrix` with elements of the same type.

---

A sample is available [on Github](https://github.com/manish-in-java/stackoverflow-questions/tree/master/43971408).

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation and code examples. I really appreciate it. Question answered.